# Changing line colors and types of a spj.glmer probability plots of covariates by group

Tags: r, sjplot

I am trying to plot the interaction between a fixed effect and random factor. sjPlot seems like a good package for this, but I am having trouble changing the line types and colors. I would like the change the line colors to a gray-scale scheme with different line types to differentiate the groups. I've experimented with the `geom.color` argument and `sjp.setTheme` function, but so far have not been able to get the desired results.

The example code below shows my initial attempts, borrowing from the example on the [sjPlot](http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjp.glmer/) website:

```
data(efc)

efc$hi_qol <- dicho(efc$quol_5)

efc$grp = as.factor(efc$e15relat)
  levels(x = efc$grp) <- get_labels(efc$e15relat)

mydf <- data.frame(hi_qol = efc$hi_qol,
                   sex = to_factor(efc$c161sex),
                   c12hour = efc$c12hour,
                   neg_c_7 = efc$neg_c_7,
                   grp = efc$grp)
fit <- glmer(hi_qol ~ sex + c12hour + neg_c_7 + (1 | grp),
              data = mydf, family = binomial("logit"))

sjp.glmer(fit, type="ri.slope", facet.grid=F, vars="neg_c_7")
```

To change the line colors, I tried setting `geom.colors="black"`, but that didn't appear to do anything.

```
sjp.glmer(fit, type="ri.slope", facet.grid=F, geom.colors="black", vars="neg_c_7")
```

Next I tried changing the theme used by sjPlot to change the line type, but that didn't work either.

```
sjp.setTheme(geom.linetype = c(1:8))
sjp.glmer(fit, type="ri.slope", facet.grid=F, vars="neg_c_7")
```

Am I missing something obvious or is changing the line types and colors more complex?

Comment: `geom.colors` does not apply to the plot-type `ri.slope`. If you want to plot interaction (e.g. with `sjp.int()`), you could use for instance `sjp.int(fit, geom.colors = "gs")` (for grey scale, see `?sjp.grpfrq` for details on the `geom.colors` argument). However, you cannot change the line type, since the linetype-aesthetics is not mapped in the ggplot-object build by the sjp-function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sjPlot-package does not support changing the line type - only the color. Linetype aesthetics is currently not mapped by the sjp-functions. However, you could access the data that is used for the plot and create your own interaction plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sjmisc)
data(efc)
# create binary response
y <- ifelse(efc$neg_c_7 < median(stats::na.omit(efc$neg_c_7)), 0, 1)
# create data frame for fitted model
mydf <- data.frame(y = as.factor(y),
sex = as.factor(efc$c161sex),
barthel = as.numeric(efc$barthtot))
# fit model
fit <- glm(y ~ sex * barthel, data = mydf, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

p <- sjp.int(fit, geom.colors = "gs")
ggplot(p$data.list[[1]], aes(x = x, y = y, linetype = grp)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Changing the colors for interaction plots works with the `geom.colors`-argument, see *Details* in `?sjp.grpfrq`.

Comment: I think I will add a linetype-aes to the functions, so you can create b/w Plots more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this with sjplot but you could use the `interaction.plot` function to generate the plot and add `col= c(...)` to change the colours of the line.

```
interaction.plot(factor, factor, fit, .. col = c("red","blue"))
```